# ¿Tuvo la "Ortografia kastellana, nueva i perfeta" alguna repercusión importante en el siglo XVII?

Tags: ortografía, historia

[Gonzalo Correas Íñigo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzalo_Correas) es conocido principalmente por ser el impulsor del principio fonetista en la ortografía castellana frente al etimologista, bajo el criterio de que a cada fonema debe corresponder un signo en la escritura o grafema. Su obra más conocida es la *Ortografia kastellana, nueva i perfeta*, de 1630, en la que (entre otras reformas) propuso reducir el número de letras, por ejemplo sustituyendo la *c* y la *q* por la *k* o suprimiendo la *h* muda.

[Podemos consultar aquí](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice:Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta.pdf) parte de la obra, que comienza así:

> Supuesto ke ɑvemos dicho lɑrgɑmente en el Arte grɑnde de Kɑstellɑno los ɑbusos de lɑs letrɑs, ke tiene el uso komun, ɑki rrepetiremos en sumɑ lo mɑlo pɑrɑ dexɑrlo, i lo bueno pɑrɑ usɑrlo: tomɑndo por giɑ i norte estɑ rreglɑ de todos sɑbidɑ, i ɑdmitidɑ por verdɑderɑ, ke se ɑ́ de eskrivir, komo se pronunziɑ, i pronunziɑr, komo se eskrive: i lɑ pɑlɑvrɑ ortogrɑﬁɑ su ministrɑ: ke giɑndonos por ellɑ sɑldremos bien del pielɑgo del vulgo rrudo. Ortogrɑﬁɑ es pɑlɑvrɑ Griegɑ, ke kiere dezir derechɑ mɑnerɑ de eſkrivir...

La cuestión es: dado que cuando se publicó esta obra la RAE aún no existía, ¿tuvo esta obra alguna repercusión o impacto en su época o en las décadas siguientes? ¿Hubo alguien más allá del propio Gonzalo Correas que escribiera obras de importancia usando esta ortografía? ¿Fue esta obra la causa de algún cambio, por leve que fuera, en la ortografía del español?

Comment: @walen yo nada. Ahora, el que escribió [el texto de donde copié y pegué](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta.pdf/18), no sé... :-D

Answer (score 2):

[Gregorio Mayans i Siscar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorio_Mayans) fue, según Wikipedia, *«un erudito, jurista, historiador, lingüista y polígrafo español; el mayor representante, junto a Benito Feijoo, de la primera Ilustración española»*.

En 1770 escribía, como parte de sus comentarios a una traducción de las *Epístolas* de Cicerón hecha por Pedro Simón, [lo siguiente](https://books.google.es/books?id=ZwqCn_ruHR4C&dq=gonzalo%20correas&hl=es&pg=PR37#v=onepage&q=gonzalo%20correas&f=false) (énfasis mío):

> Gonzalo Correas a la poquedad de los precetos neceſſarios añadiò la ſingularidad del artificio, con que facilitò mucho la enſeñanza de la Lengua Latina : i huviera logrado la eſtimacion que merecía , ſi ſe huviera abſtenido de apartarſe del comun modo de hablar de los Gramaticos , variando ( aunque ingenioſamente ) la orden de las Declinaciones , i Conjugaciones : **por lo qual le tuvieron por ridiculo , i ſus Gramaticas , Caſtellana , Latina , i Griega , comprehendidas en ſu *Trilingue* , se conſumieron en las eſpecierias**.

Lo anterior no obstante, D. Gregorio tenía en estima el trabajo de Gonzalo Correas, y de hecho recomendaba a sus discípulos su estudio, como puede leerse en *Escritores del Reyno de Valencia*, tomo segundo (1748):

> En Valencia en la Imprenta del Autor 1728, en 8. Seguía Bordazar la Ortografia mas comun , y corriente ; pero **obſervando que D. Gregorio Mayans y Siſcàr ſe apartava de ella en muchas coſas , le preguntò las razones que tenia para ello** ; y aviendolas oido , eſcriviò en pocos dias una Ortografia totalmente conforme à la idea que avia oido , y la preſentò à ſu amigo ; **el qual**, aunque alabò la facilidad conque avia comprehendido , y explicado ſu Siſtema ortografico , viò que ſe avia eſtendido demaſiadamente en 51. hojas en fol, y que para ſu mayor iluſtracion podia añadirſe algo , y **le aconſejò que abreviaſſe ſu Obra , examinando antes la doctrina de Matheo Aleman , y de Gonzalo Correas**.

Ambos textos dan a entender que **las propuestas de Correas, si bien apreciadas por algunos, fueron en general ridiculizadas por sus contemporáneos y no tuvieron mayor impacto**.

Lo cual no quita para que Gonzalo Correas fuese estimado por sus otras obras y traducciones. Por ejemplo, [Francisco de Quevedo lo usó como fuente](https://books.google.es/books?id=awABAAAAMAAJ&dq=gonzalo%20correas&hl=es&pg=PA572#v=onepage&q=gonzalo%20correas&f=false) a la hora de traducir *Epicteto*.